# Getting RangeError (index) in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to read data from a Firestore document. By means of a StreamBuilder I am fetching the documents of all `customers`. Then, I am running a check for the customers document with the currently logged in user id.

Next I am looking to fetch `cart` array field of this document from Firestore. However, I am getting a range error: **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2**

Currently, I have 3 items in the `cart` array.

**Firestore Document:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: (){ FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();},
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    if(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('uid') == currUserId){
                      cart = snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart');
                      cartValue = snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cartValue');
                      qty = snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['qty'];
                      return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.w),
                      child: 
                      snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart').isEmpty ? 
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(height: 22.5.h,),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 33.w, 
                                  height: 30.w,
                                  child: const Image(image: AssetImage("./assets/images/empty_cart.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                                Center(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 75.w,
                                      child: Text("You have no items in your cart, please browse our products to add them here.", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 27.5.h,),
                            Column(
                              children: [
                                CustomButton(width: 90.w, height: 15.w, color: primary, onTap: (){}, text: "Browse Products", fontColor: white, borderColor: primary),
                                SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      : 
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 100.w,
                                height: 40.h,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ListView.builder(
                                        itemCount: (cart.length),
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                          return CartTile(
                                            onTap: (){}, 
                                            imgUrl: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['imgUrls'][0],
                                            // cartItems[index].product.imgUrls[0], 
                                            productName: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['name'], 
                                            productWeight: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['weight'].toDouble(), 
                                            productPrice: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['price'].toDouble(), 
                                            onSubtract: (){
                                              if(cart[index]['qty'] > 1){
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').doc(currUserId).update({
                                                  'cartValue' : FieldValue.increment(-(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['price'].toDouble()))
                                                });
                                                cart[index]['qty']--;
                                                print(cart);
                                                print(cart.length);
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').doc(currUserId).update({
                                                  'cart': cart,
                                                });
                                                setState(() {
                                                
                                                });
                                              } 
                                              print("On Subtract:");
                                              print(cart[index]['qty']);
                                              print(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['qty']);
                                            }, 
                                            onAdd: (){
                                              if(cart[index]['qty'] < snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['units']){
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').doc(currUserId).update({
                                                  'cartValue' : FieldValue.increment(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['product']['price'].toDouble())
                                                });
                                                cart[index]['qty']++;
                                                print(cart);
                                                print(cart.length);
                                                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers').doc(currUserId).update({
                                                  'cart': cart,
                                                });
                                                setState(() {
                                                
                                                });
                                              } 
                                              print("On Add:");
                                              print(cart[index]['qty']);
                                              print(snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['qty']);
                                            },
                                            qty: snapshot.data!.docs[index].get('cart')[index]['qty'],
                                          );
                                        }
                                      ),    
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  CustomTextField(width: 57.w, controller: couponController, hintText: "Enter Coupon Code", label: "Coupon Code", keyboardType: TextInputType.text),
                                  SizedBox(width: 3.w,),
                                  CustomButton(width: 30.w, height: 15.w, color: primary, onTap: (){}, text: "Apply", fontColor: white, borderColor: primary),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Sub Total", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                  
                                  Text(cartValue.toCurrencyString(leadingSymbol: "₹", useSymbolPadding: true), style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,),),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Wallet", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                  Text("- ${200.toCurrencyString(leadingSymbol: "₹", useSymbolPadding: true)}", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Discount", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                  Text("- ${300.toCurrencyString(leadingSymbol: "₹", useSymbolPadding: true)}", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Delivery Charge", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                  Text(0.toCurrencyString(leadingSymbol: "₹", useSymbolPadding: true), style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: black, fontSize: 3.w,)),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                              Container(
                                width: 100.w,
                                height: 0.5,
                                color: grey,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 1.h,),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text("Total", style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: primary, fontSize: 4.w, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                  
                                  Text((cartValue-300-200).toCurrencyString(leadingSymbol: "₹", useSymbolPadding: true), style: globalTextStyle.copyWith(color: primary, fontSize: 4.w, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                                ],
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                              CustomButton(width: 90.w, height: 15.w, color: primary, onTap: (){}, text: "Checkout", fontColor: white, borderColor: primary),
                              SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                    }
                    
                  }
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text('Error');
                  } else {
                    return const SizedBox();
                  }
                },
                
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Please help me find out the error in my code and how to solve it.

Comment: you are using same variable as `index` in same tree, please change theme and update question again.

Comment: @eamirho3ein thanks it works properly after I change the nested index variable's name.